# Install python3.6.8 failed in MacOS Sonoma useing pyenv

Tags: python-3.6, pyenv, macos-sonoma

I'm trying to install python3.6.8 onto a Mac using pyenv. However, I'm getting the error:

```
BUILD FAILED (OS X 14.3.1 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/12/9cwdctlj7hs4g9w160xyg6rr0000gn/T/python-build.20240301183819.4919
Results logged to /var/folders/12/9cwdctlj7hs4g9w160xyg6rr0000gn/T/python-build.20240301183819.4919.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking for long double support... yes
checking size of long double... 8
checking size of _Bool... 1
checking size of off_t... 8
checking whether to enable large file support... no
checking size of time_t... 8
checking for pthread_t... yes
checking size of pthread_t... 8
configure: error: Unexpected output of 'arch' on OSX
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

When I install with brew, I get this error：
No available formula with the name "python@3.6". Did you mean python@3.9, python@3.8, python@3.7, python@3.12, python@3.11, python@3.10 or python-yq?

Comment: Python versions are officially supported for 5 years. 3.6 is out for this time frame. You will still find sources to get the version, but you should consider upgrading. If you really need the old version take the risks into account, and maybe apply some isolation (e.g. run it in a container).

Answer (score 0):

Try this to install e.g. Python 3.8.5 on macOS Sonoma using pyenv, on an Apple ARM chip, worked fine for me. (*you might be able to find a similar patch for Python 3.6.8*)

```
brew install openssl readline sqlite3 xz zlib
```

Next, you can try installing Python 3.8.5 using a patch provided by Homebrew. This patch is specifically designed to address compatibility issues with the Apple ARM chips:

```
pyenv install --patch 3.8.5 <<(curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/formula-patches/113aa84/python/3.8.3.patch\?full_index\=1)
```